# Please explain Tim Pope's Effortless Ctags with Git

Tags: git, unix, ctags

Just installing Tim Pope's [Effortless Ctags with Git](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html) here. It's a bit light on explanation. I get the general idea, but could someone explicate the details? Specifically:

```
trap 'rm -f "$dir/$$.tags"' EXIT
```

Why remove this file via a trap, rather than just every time the script is run?

```
git ls-files | \
    ctags --tag-relative -L - -f"$dir/$$.tags" --languages=-javascript,sql
mv "$dir/$$.tags" "$dir/tags"
```

Why put the tags file into a temporary variable `$$.tags` and then move it to `tags` on the next line?

Comment: The `$$.tags` trick is probably meant to guarantee that you'll never see a partial `tags` file; the old one remains in place until the new one is complete. I don't have an answer to the first part.

Comment: The first part is to ensure that you never end up with a "left-over" partial tags file if e.g. git crashes in the middle of the script.

Answer (score 2):

The answers are all in the comments.  I hope it's OK to restate those comments here in an answer, just so that this question may be able to be marked as "answered."

> Why remove this file via a trap, rather than just every time the script is run?

I think [Evan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838117/please-explain-tim-popes-effortless-ctags-with-git#comment45955199_28838117) is right about this.  Note that Mr. Pope is using `set -e`, so the script will exit immediately if `git` or `mv` fail.  If he just put the `rm` at the end of the script instead of in a `trap`, you might end up littering `*.tags` files around if any commands fail before the `rm` is reached.  I like this use of `trap ... EXIT` for cleaning up temporary files.

> Why put the tags file into a temporary variable $$.tags and then move it to tags on the next line?

And here I think [Mr. Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838117/please-explain-tim-popes-effortless-ctags-with-git#comment45945926_28838117) is correct: You probably wouldn't want your editor/IDE to try and use a half-written tags file.  Better to let the potentially lengthy rebuild of tags complete and move the complete database into place in one atomic move.  (Please no comments about the atomicity of `rename(2)`!)

Also, what if you checkout one branch, then checkout another before the first `ctags` command has completed?  While his scripts don't look to prevent multiple firings of `ctags` into the background, writing to `$$.tags` will at least ensure that the last `ctags` to complete will result in a complete (if not reasonable) tags file.  Contrast this with multiple `ctags` processes all writing to a single `tags` file simultaneously, which I bet could leave you with an invalid database.